# Where do I insert headers in a ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried:

```
$("#wiki").on('click', function(e) {
  var q = $(this).data('subject');
  $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=test&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max?callback=?", {
    srsearch: q,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    prop: "text",
    section: 0,
    format: "json"
  }, function(data) {
      headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
      },
      $("#results").empty();
      $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
      $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
    });
  },
  );
});
```

And

```
$("#wiki").on('click', function(e) {
  var q = $(this).data('subject');
  $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=test&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max?callback=?", {
    srsearch: q,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    prop: "text",
    section: 0,
    format: "json"
  }, 
  headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
  },
  function(data) {
      $("#results").empty();
      $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
      $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
    });
  },
  );
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no construct to add headers in a `$.getJSON` call. You need to either use the `beforeSend` property of a full `$.ajax()` request, or use `$.ajaxSetup()` to apply the same `beforeSend` property to all AJAX calls, whatever jQuery method is used to create them.

Also note that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header should be placed in a response, not a request. It will make no difference to what you are sending.

If you are attempting to avoid the CORS warning that is shown in some browsers, which suggests the use of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, then you need to add it in your server side code instead. Assuming you do not have access to the server code (as you're calling Wikipedia in this case) and you are getting a CORS error, then you cannot call that domain through JS code.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but aren't those response headers they're trying to send?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i used:  `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
    }
  });` but i still get `Refused to execute script from..because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: I'm unable to diagnose that error as there are a lot of problems with the code you've shown. Personally, I'm not even sure that it's possible to get data from wikipedia via a JS AJAX request due to the CORS issue I mentioned above.

Comment: Wikipedia API has CORS enabled, so that's not a problem (and the error message doesn't have anything to do with CORS anyway.) It's more likely that the request URL is wrong. If you visit the URL, it just shows the help page.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thew search works, yet I was trying to enable the images with the code above http://blog.comperiosearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/instantsearch.html